# Regular Expression regex to validate input: Two words with a space between

Tags: php, regex

i need to use a regular expression to validate a field with php that has to have two words separated by a space like: "First Last" but i cant find one that fits my purposes, can anyone help me?

The best i've done is `^[a-zA-Z0-9_\s]*$` but with this i can have more than one space and anywhere in the field and i want only between the words. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 9):

Something like `^\w+\s\w+$` ought to work for this case. But you don't necessarily need to use regular expressions for this, you could just use `explode()`.

Comment: +1: Matches the OP's question exactly. But I would have upvoted you anyway, just for getting rid of that `{1}` abomination. :D

Answer (score 4):

```
^[^\s]+\s[^\s]+$
```

- `[^\s]+` matches one or more characters, except whitespace characters;
- `\s` matches a single whitespace character.

Answer (score 0):

This might do the trick

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ {1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

Comment: here works like this: ^\w+\s{1}\w+$ :P And if i want only letters A-Za-z instead of \w (alphanumeric)? I cant fit it to the regex :o

Comment: i have to put the \s but it's not serving my purpose, estrangely if i put a space in the beggining or at the end and only word it validates correctly :s ^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s{1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+$