# Strip non alphanumeric characters and limit string to two words

Tags: php

I'm trying to strip non-alphanumeric characters from a string and limit the string to two words. i.e:

```
foo bar baz    => foo-bar
boo   * test   => boo-test
te%st_foo      => test-foo
```

So far I've got this:

```
$term = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9 ]/', '', $term);
$words = explode(" ", $term);
$generated = strtolower(implode(" ",array_splice($words,0,2)));
$term = preg_replace('!\s+!', '-', $term);
```

But going wrong somewhere, these are snippets I've just snapped together to try and get the results I'm after.

The problem is really if there is more than 1 space in a string etc.

Help appreciated :)

Thanks

Comment: `foo bar baz    => foo-bar`? Can you explain this?

Comment: This seems to be a possible duplicate of [Regular Expression regex to validate input: Two words with a space between](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5060895/regular-expression-regex-to-validate-input-two-words-with-a-space-between)

Comment: @fredley I want to limit the output string to only two words, word1-word2

Answer (score 1):

First normalize the string by removing excess space as follows:

```
preg_replace('/[ ]+/', ' ', $term);
```

Then do the rest, it will work.

Answer (score 0):

For reducing multiple [white]spaces to a single space use:

```
$string = preg_replace("/[ \t\n\r]+/", " ", $string);
```

Do this immediately before your `explode`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/is', '-', $str);
$str = trim(str_replace('--', '-', $str), '-');
// now we have array of words
$str = explode('-', $str);
$str = $str[0].'-'.$str[1];
```

**UPD:**

```
<?php
    $str = 'foo&*^%#*$&@^     bar          asjdhakhsgd';
    $str = preg_replace('/[^a-z]+/is', '-', $str);
    $str = trim(str_replace('--', '-', $str), '-');
    $str = explode('-', $str);
    $str = $str[0].'-'.$str[1];

    echo $str; // foo-bar
?>
```